# libgdx loading preferences for LwjglApplicationConfiguration

Tags: java, libgdx, lwjgl

I am using [preferences](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Preferences) from libgdx. I have stored width and height keys with values in ../prefs/MyPreferences file.

In my DesktopLauncher main method, I am doing following configuration before starting new LWJGL App:

```
private static void main() {
    LwjglApplicationConfiguration desktopConfiguration = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
    Preferences preferences = new Preferences("MyPreferences");
    desktopConfiguration.title = "My Game";
    desktopConfiguration.width = preferences.getInteger("width");
    desktopConfiguration.height = preferences.getInteger("height");
    new LwjglApplication(new Game(preferences), desktopConfiguration);
}
```

I am getting NPE, and reason is because application is not loaded yet in order to use this preferences.
So my question is, how can I fill configuration properties such as width,height,etc. by loading values from preferences if preferences is not loaded first?

Comment: I think java Properties should do what I need (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html). If I use Java Properties over Preferences, can I use this also this for Android and iOS devices beside desktop ?

Comment: Instead of using libGDX Preferences, you can save those values into a JSON file. So before you run the application/game, you just read them from the file and use them for the configuration.